# Is it possible - Win Phone 8 development on Win7 using device not emulator

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

Could someone please advise if it is possible to develop for the Windows phone 8 on Windows 7 OS using the device not the Emulator.

I will be doing C++ development for that platform.

Comment: You cannot install WP8 SDK on Windows 7 OS, installer won't allow you to. See similar [question on Programmers SE site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175284/windows-phone-8-development-on-windows-7-is-it-or-will-be-possible).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can not install the required SDK on Windows 7. You need Windows 8 to install VS2012 with phone-support. If you do not need the emulator, run Win8 inside a VM. It runs pretty smooth. I set this up for me and it works very well. Even the deployment to a WP8-device and debugging.

But you will most probably not be able to run the WP8-emulator as it is a Hyper-V-machine that needs Intel VT and Win8 Pro to be present. I was not able to setup a virtual machine to pass these features to the hosted Win8-instance, yet. But if you are just fine with your device give it a shot. I run it in VMWare player. But virtual box should work, too.

Comment: I am doing game development using C++, and native development is supported on the Windows Phone 8 platform. See MS presentation: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-046 I know to run the Emulator, Windows 8 Pro+ OS is required, but since VS2012 runs on Win7 OS, I'm trying to figure out if development and testing can be done to a WinPhone 8 device on Win7 OS or do I have to upgrade to Win8 OS. Trying to avoid upgrading OS since my other development environments will be messed up since Win8 is not as sppted right now.

Comment: As to see in my answer: Run Win8 inside a VM hosted in your Win7 instance (VMWarePlayer does the job for me) if you just want to test on a device.
If you want to use the features of the emulator you probably will have to install Win8 directly on your box (at least Core i5 for Hyper-V-support). My research so far brought up no way to run the emulator inside a virtual machine.

There is no way to deploy to a WP8-device from Win7.

Answer (score 2):

not possible at all as the installer won't run

the system requirement is as [below](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-phone#product-express-phone-requirements)

**Supported operating systems**

- Windows 8 (x64)

**Supported architectures**

- 64-bit (x64)

**Hardware requirements**

- 1.6 GHz or faster processor
- 4 GB of RAM
- 4 GB of available hard disk space

**Windows Phone 8 Emulator**

- Windows 8 Pro edition or greater
- Requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)